# DOM Challenge -> Get text that is not in any element

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

here how i get my dom tree:

```
$html = file_get_contents('somefile.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom_document = new DomXPath($dom);
$dom_object = $dom_document->query('somePathHere');
```

the html structure of $dom_object:

```
<div>
  <a href='something'>some text here</a>
  I want this
</div>
```

here what i need:

```
foreach($dom_object as $value){
     echo $value->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue; //working properly
     echo 'I want this' // I don't know how to get that 'I want this' text
}
```

precisions: I would like to avoid having to make multiple xpath queries. I would like to stick with mine... Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc

Comment: Does the div have a name or id? If not, is the order in which the div tag appears, always the same (like it's always the second div beeing opened)?

Comment: Hello Ahatius. The div tag has no id and the structure is always the same...

Comment: As @Ahatius said you can add an ID for your div then you can get the text.

Comment: Hello MahanGM. How would adding an id to the div solve my problem?

Comment: @Mark I'm not ver keen on DOM, but there should be some way to reference to the div, then remove child-tags, and just take the div content itself.

Comment: The problem is that as mentioned in the original post, I also use the content of the child tag...

Answer (score 0):

Use nodeType to get text nodes :

```
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    if($node -> nodeType == 3) {
        echo $node -> nodeValue . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Explanation : in php DOMDocument, any text is inside a node. In your case, it's a text node, meaning 3 according to PHP's XML_NODE_CONSTANTS

For details : http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Comment: My node has a type of 1... so what you are suggesting is not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the expected structure of your xml, but this works for your specific request:

```
/html/body/div/text()
```

This selects text nodes with the immediate parent of the div in question only.  You could also use the general `//div/text()`, but more specific queries are usually better/faster.

Comment: Hello Explosion Pills... Thks for trying to help. Nevertheless, as mentionned I am seeking for a solution that does not require to have multiple xpath queries...

Comment: Please reread my answer.  You can use *either* of those queries .. you don't need both.